# Define more than one onLoad in the same js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i define more than one onload function (but different!) 
in the same js file,

for ex,

file.js:

```
//---on load forpage1
$( document ).ready( handler ){ 
    do something one
}

//---on load for page2
$( document ).ready( handler ){ 
    do something else
}
```

and import it in both of the 2 pages:
for ex:

page1:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
</head>
```

page2:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing that?

Comment: you dont need seperate loads and if you add that will not make any difference

Comment: You can just put everything in one onload? Why would you not do that?

Comment: no because i want to do things at onload page1, and do another things when page2 loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you ask this because you want to execute different code on the other page.

You could for example check location.href to see which page is currently being called.

More usual though is to use server side scripting to determine the current page and refer to the javascript accordingly.

**Edit for an example:**

```
$(function () {
    var page = window.location.pathname;

    if (page == "/index.html") {
        // code here
    }
    else if (page == "/contact.html") {
        // other code here
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, its very neer for what i want! how i check location.href? can you help me with exxample?

Comment: I've added a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're trying to achieve. If you want several functions to run when your page loads, the code in your post is almost correct:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    console.log("Function 1 running");
});
$(document).ready(function() { 
    console.log("Function 2 running");
}
```

You can also pre-define these functions if you want, and pass them to your `$(document).ready()` call:

```
function handler_1() { 
    console.log("Handler_1 is running");
}

function handler_2() {
    console.log("Handler_2 is running");
}

$(document).ready(handler_1);
$(document).ready(handler_2);
```

And you can even use the jQuery shortcut `$()`:

```
$(handler_1);
$(handler_2);
```

---

But if you want only one function to run when the page loads - depending on which page loaded - you'll need to take another approach. You could define all your code in `script.js`, and load `init_page1.js` from page 1, `init_page2.js` from page 2, etc. Those `init` files would call whichever setup function is appropriate for the page.

Alternatively, you could add a `data` attribute on your body tag indicating what page it's on, and have your `$(document).ready()` call the correct handler. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var page_type = $('body').data('page-type');
    if (page_type == 'home') { 
        handler_1();
    } else if (page_type == 'profile') { 
        handler_2();
    }
});
```

And then, in your HTML file:

```
<body data-page-type="profile">
```

Possibly the neatest solution, though, is to have the callback functions determine whether they're relevant to the page. That way you can re-use them wherever you like. So your script would look something more like this:

```
function handler_1() { // Only for home page
    if ($('body').data('page-type') != 'home') {
        return;
    }
    console.log("I'm the handler_1 function");
}

function handler_2() { // Only for profile page
    if ($('body').data('page-type') != 'profile') { 
        return;
    }
}

$(handler_1);
$(handler_2);
```

Really, though, if you can avoid coding this into your JavaScript, you should. It's better to only include scripts that you know are required for that particular page to function.

Comment: This question is unclear and an appropriate answer cannot be inferred from its content.

Comment: thank you a lot. it is can work and be a solution for my question.. but it seems that Arie user gave me a shorter solution.. any way, thank you very much man! :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to $( document ).ready, which is called after the DOM is fully loaded for the current HTML file, including all images, the $(window).load is another method to detect DOM readiness that is not fired until all sub-elements, like iframes have been loaded and are available for use.

As to your original question, you can define as many $( document ).ready functions as you like; they are executed in the order they are found.

Comment: i think you dont understand my question.. i want to make js file that will define all .load() of site pages, and all the pages will include this js file.           thare is a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple blocks of `$(document).ready` – but it won't solve your problem as they'll all be called once the DOM is loaded.

I'd recommend you to take a look at Paul Irish's [DOM-based Routing](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/).

Comment: thanks, but as you said it will not solve my problem, because they'll all be called once the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was very vague but I'm assuming you want multiple items to be called upon the page being loaded, in which the first example is.

```
document.ready(function(handler){
    /*Do thing one*/
    /*Do thing two*/
});
```

But if you mean for them to be called with different scenarios then you would use the handler passed in to check the status of the document and call a different item.

```
document.ready(function(handler){
    if(handler==bar)
        //Do thing one
    else if(handler==foo)
        //Do thing two
    else
        //Do thing three
});
```

Comment: how can i change the handler that in one time be 'bar' and in other time 'foo' for example?